# C# strange lambda behavior

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, iqueryable

Could someone point out why this could be happening:

I am using `NHibernate` and the `Linq` provider for it.

*The code that fails is listed here:*

```
var sequence = session.Query<T>();

var wtfSequence = sequence.Where(x => true);
var okaySequence = sequence.Where(x => x.Id > 0);
```

Debugging shows that `sequence` (which is an `IQueryable<T>`) after this contains 2 elements, which were added to the database.

***I expect the first `Where` statement to yield all elements from that sequence, but unfortunately it leaves 0 elements.***

## **(WHY???)**

The second `Where` statement, on the contrary, actually yields 2 elements as it should work.

*Here are the `NHibernate -> Sqlite` queries for the first and second `Where` statements.*

```
NHibernate: select cast(count(*) as INTEGER) as col_0_0_ from "BinaryUnitProxy_IndicatorUnitDescriptor" binaryunit0_ where @p0='true';@p0 = 'True' [Type: String (0)]

NHibernate: select cast(count(*) as INTEGER) as col_0_0_ from "BinaryUnitProxy_IndicatorUnitDescriptor" binaryunit0_ where binaryunit0_.Id>@p0;@p0 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

---

Now, if I test the same code with my `InMemoryRepository`, which stores every entity in a simple list, the `(x => true)` works absolutelty fine.

**So - why does this happen when using `NHibernate`? Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?**

Thank you.

Comment: It's most likely related to the way NHibernate treates the Expression it creates from the lambda, although goodness knows what it's doing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know NHibernate, but the problem is obvious from the generated SQL: Your database does not consider true (lowercase t) equal to True (uppercase T). In SQL server you can change this by modifying the database collation (which is a really bad idea unless you want case insensitivity for other reasons).

My guess is this is a bug in NHibernate that you need to work around. Test `t => 1 == 1` instead of `t => true`, which might work depending on how the NHibernate code is written.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is a bug in NHibernate based on the SqLite output that you show.  You could try `X => X.Id == X.Id` rather than `X => true` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me. Its converting a boolean operation to a string evaluation, and even that's screwed up, as it sets up the query with `true` and evaluates using `True`, so a case-sensitive test would fail.